# Pickle EOFError .pkl keras with python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, pickle, mnist

in this week i'm trying to do some classification exercises and I start from MNIST handwriting detector. I use some file from internet to recognize the digit from paper but i'm trying to train ***own*** model with neural nets.

I have to pickle data to format .pkl file that recognizer can read the data. I train my model with keras and I get with that well trained model. First my problem was that I couldn't pickle data but I had to add function "make keras picklable" and after that I managed to pickle.

Now the problem is that when i'm trying to load pickled model I get error EOFError. I think that i'm using pickle right way but the problem is mayby in keras. I'm using Ubuntu16.04 and python 2.7. The code files is included below:

**OwnClassificationtrain-file:**

```
import types
import tempfile
import keras
import keras.models
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
# load data
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
# reshape to be [samples][pixels][width][height]
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, 28, 28).astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, 28, 28).astype('float32')
# normalize inputs from 0-255 to 0-1
X_train = X_train / 255
X_test = X_test / 255
# one hot encode outputs
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
num_classes = y_test.shape[1]

# define the larger model
def larger_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(30, (5, 5), input_shape=(1, 28, 28), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(15, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

def make_keras_picklable():
    def __getstate__(self):
        model_str = ""
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.hdf5', delete=True) as fd:
            keras.models.save_model(self, fd.name, overwrite=True)
            model_str = fd.read()
        d = { 'model_str': model_str }
        return d

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.hdf5', delete=True) as fd:
            fd.write(state['model_str'])
            fd.flush()
            model = keras.models.load_model(fd.name)
        self.__dict__ = model.__dict__


    cls = keras.models.Model
    cls.__getstate__ = __getstate__
    cls.__setstate__ = __setstate__

model = larger_model()
# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=1, batch_size=200)
# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Large CNN Error: %.2f%%" % (100-scores[1]*100))
make_keras_picklable()
with open('filename.pkl', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(model, file, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

**Recognition-file:**

```
# Import the modules
import cv2
import cPickle
from skimage.feature import hog
import numpy as np

# Load the classifier
with open('traineddata.pkl','rb') as f:  #load working with originalfile with command clf=joblib.load('digits_cls.pkl') (from sklearn.externals import joblib)
    clf = cPickle.load(f)

print(clf)

# Read the input image 
im = cv2.imread("photo10.jpg")

# Convert to grayscale and apply Gaussian filtering
im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
im_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(im_gray, (5, 5), 0)

# Threshold the image
ret, im_th = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Find contours in the image
image, ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(im_th.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Get rectangles contains each contour
rects = [cv2.boundingRect(ctr) for ctr in ctrs]

# For each rectangular region, calculate HOG features and predict
# the digit using Linear SVM.
for rect in rects:
    # Draw the rectangles
    cv2.rectangle(im, (rect[0], rect[1]), (rect[0] + rect[2], rect[1] + rect[3]), (0, 255, 0), 3) 
    # Make the rectangular region around the digit
    leng = int(rect[3] * 1.6)
    pt1 = int(rect[1] + rect[3] // 2 - leng // 2)
    pt2 = int(rect[0] + rect[2] // 2 - leng // 2)
    roi = im_th[pt1:pt1+leng, pt2:pt2+leng]
    # Resize the image
    roi = cv2.resize(roi, (28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    roi = cv2.dilate(roi, (3, 3))
    # Calculate the HOG features
    roi_hog_fd = hog(roi, orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(14, 14), cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualise=False)
    nbr = clf.predict(np.array([roi_hog_fd], 'float64'))
    cv2.putText(im, str(int(nbr[0])), (rect[0], rect[1]),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 2, (128, 255, 0), 3)

imS = cv2.resize(im, (960, 540))
cv2.imshow("Resulting Image with Rectangular ROIs", imS)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Originaltrain-file:**

```
# Import the modules
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn import datasets
from skimage.feature import hog
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

# Load the dataset
dataset = datasets.fetch_mldata("MNIST Original")

# Extract the features and labels
features = np.array(dataset.data, 'int16') 
labels = np.array(dataset.target, 'int')

# Extract the hog features
list_hog_fd = []
for feature in features:
    fd = hog(feature.reshape((28, 28)), orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(14, 14), cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualise=False)
    list_hog_fd.append(fd)
hog_features = np.array(list_hog_fd, 'float64')

print "Count of digits in dataset", Counter(labels)

# Create an linear SVM object
clf = LinearSVC()

# Perform the training
clf.fit(hog_features, labels)

# Save the classifier
joblib.dump(clf, "digits_cls.pkl", compress=3)
```

Link for photo10.jpg:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnQPQ.jpg
I think that I shouldn't mix keras and sklearn but I have no idea how to replace sklearn's functions in Recognition-file.

Comment: Now I understand that impossible to merge sklearn and keras but is it possible to do deep learning things and neural networks with sklearn?

Comment: Is it possible to do model with scikit-neuralnetwork for handwritten digit recognizer?